# Using functions to find indeterminate forms

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

The question is to use two functions f(x) and g(x) to show that ∞ - ∞ (infinity - infinity) is indeterminate.
I don't really know how to get started on this. I think I need to find two limits for f(x) and g(x) that are both infinity. But how to I show that subtracting them is indeterminate?

Edit: In the example we were shown, lim x --> 0 was used. But that was for the indeterminate form 0∞.  I don't know if that applies here or not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$
f(x) = \csc^2x \\ g(x) = \cot^2 x \\ h(x) = 1/x^2
$$
and look at the limit as $x\to 0$ of the expressions $f(x)-g(x)$ and $f(x)-h(x)$.

Both of these expressions are of the form $\infty - \infty$

But 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} (f(x) - g(x)) = 1 \\ \lim_{x\to 0} (f(x) - h(x)) = \frac13
$$
This shows that $\infty - \infty$ could be $1$ or $\frac13$; for that matter it could be $0$ (consider $f(x)-f(x)$).

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, could you explain how f(x) -g(x) = 1 and f(x) - h(x) = 1/3?   I thought that they all would equal infinity?

Comment: @Jordan He is just giving you the answers for those limits. You can verify them with L'Hospital's Rule. It's a good exercise

Comment: On the other hand, the first one is particularly easy:  Since $csc^2x - \cot^2x = 1$ for all values of angles where they are both finite, "obviously" the limit as $x\to$ any real value (or for that matter even any complex value) must be $1$.

Answer (score 0):

"Indeterminate" means "not having a unique value" as $x$ tends to whatever the problem says (I am guessing $x \rightarrow 0$ or $x \rightarrow \infty$, but you really should specify and not make the community you are asking for help guess).  I will assume $x \rightarrow \infty$.

So, to show indeterminacy, I will exhibit three examples of the function pair $f(x), g(x)$ with different limiting behaviors of the difference $[f(x)-g(x)]$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Example 1: $f(x) = g(x) = x$.  Here $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}[f(x) - g(x)] = 0$.

Example 2: $f(x) = x^2, \; g(x) = x$.

Example 3: See Mark Fischler's answer.:)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

The part that I don't understand is that when you use different values for f and g. Wouldn't you expect a different answer? I don't really understand how that makes it indeterminate.

Comment: Well consider a form that is not indeterminate: $1 / \infty$.  In detail: if you have
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \mbox{(some real cosntant)}, \quad
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = \infty,
$$
then, no matter which $f, g$ you use, as long as they satisfy the above conditions, you will get
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow} {f(x) \over g(x)} = 0.
$$

In a high-level summary: The goal is, knowing the asymptotic behavior of $f, g$, to be able to ascertain the asymptotic behavior of an expression involving these two.  When we cannot do that, the latter expression is indeterminate.